# Circuit appeared to work for a few minutes at first, then poof! Can you help me figure it out? Diagram included

Tags: pcb, poe, load-regulation

thank you for taking the time.

I have this PoE design that takes 48V and knocks it down to 5V for powering generic USB devices.

[image][image]
[image]
I received some new boards and when testing them, discovered they worked exactly as intended. Load tester seemed to be fine too, as it was able to regulate up to >15W of load which was my target.

As soon as I tested it on a real USB device ( a raspberry pi in this case) my 5V usb monitor died, registering a voltage of >36V before doing so. Luckily the Pi survived, but I'm left clueless as to why 48V appeared on my 5V rail.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check all solder connections, but especially the feedback line. Failure of feedback could cause full input voltage on regulated line. Also check switch for failed short. Overload might cause a failed switch in a short

Comment: 1N5823 is only specified for 40V. Note your circuit is not PoE as there is no ethernet involved and no detection circuitry.

Comment: Does that RJ45 jack have integrated magnetics?  I couldn't find a good datasheet.  If it doesn't, your circuit isn't isolated from the Ethernet.  Why do you have your 5V rail connected directly to the jack?

Comment: For future designs consider including a crowbar circuit. That's a circuit that protects the electronics from overvoltage by short circuiting either the input or output of your regulator when it detects an overvoltage condition on the output. You also need a fuse somewhere that blows as soon as the overvoltage protection is triggered.

Comment: Likely the diode. But that design should not be called PoE, as it just uses a 8P8C connector for unisolated power input. That is dangerous even for passive PoE. Even passive PoE should use diode bridge to handle crossover cables, use two diode bridges to not feed power back to the unpowered pairs, and use an isolated DC/DC converter.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who replied! I really appreciate your help learning the ropes, and I've gained quite a bit here.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with your PCB layout.

L2 should feed directly into the output capacitor C3, but you've routed that connection via the feedback trace.

That trace will see large currents and regulation will suffer, perhaps to the point of instability.

It's usually best to look up the reference design for the buck converter IC and take inspiration from its layout.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll try to take a look at the reference layout designs first from now on. I think I'm going to have another go at this one that includes this and what others have said above